# Code Review for filling tableview cells with response returned from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

## Connection Class

```
-(NSDictionary *)getResponseFromSearchByRoutewithUrl:(NSString *)url  :(HttpCompletionBlock)completionHandler {
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSDictionary *responseDictionary;
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest: urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    //check if we encountered an error
    if(error != nil){
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }else{
        //get and check the HTTP status code
        NSInteger HTTPStatusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
        if (HTTPStatusCode != 200) {
            NSLog(@"HTTP status code = %ld", (long)HTTPStatusCode);
        }



        [task resume];
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            if(data != nil){
                NSError *parseError = nil;
                NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
                NSLog(@"The response is - %@",responseDictionary);
                return completionHandler(responseDictionary,nil);

            }
            else {
                return completionHandler(nil,error);

            }
        }];
    }
}];
[task resume];
return responseDictionary;

}
```

## ViewController having Table view cells Class

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 _appDelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      [[ConnectionManager sharedConnectionManager]getResponseFromSearchByRoutewithUrl:_urlString :^(NSDictionary *responseDictionary, NSError *error) {
    if(error == nil)
    {

     _appDelegate.flightsArray=[responseDictionary objectForKey:@"scheduledFlights"];
         NSLog(@"the flights array is%@ ", _appDelegate.flightsArray);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error ==  %@ ",error);
    }

}];
}
```

**Table View delegate class methods**

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return _appDelegate.flightsArray.count;


}
```

Kindly Review the code and tell why the number of rows is zero...even when the response dictionary is returning dictionary...

Comment: The way you are using is not formal. In my opinion, the simplest way to fix your issue is using NSNotification to post new notification when you got responseDictionary. And in ViewController you can handle [yourTableView reloadData] if notification come. Pay attention to set _appDelegate.flightsArray value before calling [yourTableView reloadData].

Comment: So your responseDictionary is containing the desired value that you want?

Comment: YES,the response dictionary contains the desired value.I have made some changes...i have actually used NSNOTIFICATION now but the method of nsnotification doesn't get fired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     _appDelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     [[ConnectionManager sharedConnectionManager]getResponseFromSearchByRoutewithUrl:_urlString :^(NSDictionary *responseDictionary, NSError *error) {
     if(error == nil)
     {
          _appDelegate.flightsArray=[responseDictionary objectForKey:@"scheduledFlights"];
          NSLog(@"the flights array is%@ ", _appDelegate.flightsArray);
          [self performSelector:@selector(reloadTableview) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
     }
     else
     {
          NSLog(@"Error ==  %@ ",error);
     }

     }];
}

- (void)reloadTableview{
     [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```